# Refreshing a div in Drupal

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I've created the module that's loading JavaScript code. I read online that it should be refreshing my div, but it isn't and I don't know why.

This is my code:

#### .module

```
<?php
    function div_refresh_init() {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'div_refresh') . '/div_refresh.js');
    }

    function dev_refresh_menu() {
        $items = array();
        $items[] = array(
            'path' => 'div_refresh/update',
            'callback' => 'div_refresh_update',
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
            'access' => TRUE,
        );
        return $items;
    }

    function div_refresh_update() {
        $html = get_data();
        print drupal_to_js(array('html' => $html));
        exit();
    }
```

#### JavaScript code

```
function autoupdate() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "div_refresh/update",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var result = Drupal.parseJson(data);
            $("div.autorefresh").fadeIn("slow").html(result['html']);
        }
    });
}

if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval("autoupdate()", 5000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JS looks fine (as long as there is actually a `<div>` on the page with the class `autorefresh`); I think it's the menu callback function that's the problem.

The code you've got looks like it's for Drupal 5 and I'm going to take a stab that you're actually using Drupal 6? If so your implementation of `hook_menu()` should look like this:

```
function dev_refresh_menu() {
  $items['div_refresh/update'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'div_refresh_update',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

You can confirm this by going directly to `www.mysite.com/div_refresh/update`, if you get a 404 then Drupal has no record of your menu item.

Also remember to clear Drupal's caches once you've made the changes otherwise the new item won't be picked up.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Yes it is for 6, but its still noe working. When I go to the url I get page not found.

Comment: That's actually good news, the only things you need to check now are that your module is installed and enabled, and then make sure you've cleared Drupal's caches. Once you do it simply has to work :)

Answer (score 0):

In setInterval avoid pass the function as string, eval is evil ;)

```
setInterval(function() { autoupdate() }, 5000);
```